# Adding fields until screen is full

Tags: blackberry, user-interface

For the sake of this question, let us suppose that I want a row of buttons. I want to put as many buttons in that row as I can fit on the screen, but no more. In other words, as long as a prospective button will not be cut off or have its text shortened, add it.

It seems that I should be able to do something like:

```
HorizontalFieldManager hfm = new HorizontalFieldManager();

int remainingWidth = Display.getWidth();

int i =0;
while(true) {
    ButtonField bf = new ButtonField("B " + i);
    remainingWidth -= bf.getWidth();
    if(remainingWidth<0)
        break;
    hfm.add(bf);
    i++;
}

add(hfm);
```

But this doesn't work. bf.getWidth() is always 0. I suspect that this is because the button has not yet been laid out when I query for the width.

So, perhaps I could just make sure the buttons are always the same size. But this won't work for a few reasons:

1. Different BB platforms have different looks for buttons and text that will fit on a button on a Curve won't fit on a button on a Storm.
2. 3rd party themes may change the look of buttons, so I can't even count on buttons being a certain size on a certain platform.

Is there no way for me to actually check the remaining space before adding a button? It feels like a fairly useful feature; am I just missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to draw the Manager before adding component to it.

You should probably add the padding too, if the button has one.

```
public class Main extends UiApplication{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main main = new Main();
        main.enterEventDispatcher();
    }

    public Main() {
        Screen main = new Screen();
        this.pushScreen(main);
        main.init();
    }
}

public class Screen extends MainScreen    {
HorizontalFieldManager hfm;
public Screen() {
    hfm = new HorizontalFieldManager();
    this.add(hfm);
}

public void init() {
    int remainingWidth = Display.getWidth();
    int i = 0;
    while(true) {
        ButtonField bf = new ButtonField("B " + i);
        hfm.add(bf);
        remainingWidth -= bf.getWidth();
        System.out.println(remainingWidth);
        if(remainingWidth <= 0) {
            hfm.delete(bf);
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're correct that `getWidth()` returns the width of the field *after* it's been laid out (that's why it's 0), but `getPreferredWidth()` will return the value that's given to the Layout Manager, and is probably what you want.

The other problem you have is that you're comparing `remainingWidth` to 0. If a button's preferred width is, say, 36 pixels, and the remaining width is 20 pixels, you'll draw a button in a spot where you don't have enough room to display it.

Try something like this:

```
HorizontalFieldManager hfm = new HorizontalFieldManager();
int remainingWidth = Display.getWidth();
for (int i; true; i++ ) {
  ButtonField bf = new ButtonField("B " + i);
  int preferredWidth = bf.getPreferredWidth();
  if ( remainingWidth < preferredWidth )
    break;
  remainingWidth -= preferredWidth;
  hfm.add(bf);
}
add(hfm);
```

Comment: getPreferredWidth() seems to return what getContentWidth() would in the ideal case. However, both values are smaller than the space actually consumed by the button. Like getContentWidth(), I think getPreferredWidth() returns the space consumed by the text but not all the padding (and such) of the button.

Comment: You could always extend the button field and override getPreferredWidth().  Then you would have complete control of how the width is declared.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make your own  HorizontalFiledManager (extends Manager) and override

```
 protected void sublayout( int maxWidth, int maxHeight ){
```

setExtent(maxWidth,maxHeight);
}
 
Get the number of childs, and with a for loop go trough and start to lay out the childs (setPosition, layoutChild).
When you lay out the child, count his width and always check if the counted width + the next child`s width is greater then maxWidth then do not lay out and break the for loop.
Hopefully this help you.